# How to find the percentage within a given range in java

Tags: java, excel, math, numbers, formula

I have a given range say from "min" to "max". The min is represented as 100% and max is represented as 0%. The average value (min+max)/2 is represented as 50%.

The input i will be giving is a value "x" within the range [min, max] and the output should be the percentage corresponding to the input provided.

For example, consider than range as [100, 300]

```
if x=100 then output=100%
if x=300 then output=0%
if x=200 then output=50%
if x=150 then output=75%
if x=250 then output=25%
```

Whatever the value of x provided within the range [min, max] the corresponding percentage should be calculated.

I have tried various logic but i cant seem to get the right formula for this problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about getting the _right formula_ for the problem.  It might be on-topic at http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Subtract the min from both the value and the max and calculate the perctange as normal...

Comment: @devnull ok i will check that..thank you :)

Comment: @MadProgrammer i cant understand clearly what your saying..can you explain more please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if start and end are variables to store the values then

1) You could just start the limits with 0 to end-start
   and value passed value - start
2) Calculate Percentage
3) Return 100-percentage

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(find_percent(100,300,100)+"%");
    System.out.println(find_percent(100,300,300)+"%");
    System.out.println(find_percent(100,300,200)+"%");
    System.out.println(find_percent(100,300,150)+"%");
    System.out.println(find_percent(100,300,250)+"%");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println(find_percent(20,40,20)+"%");
    System.out.println(find_percent(20,40,40)+"%");
    System.out.println(find_percent(20,40,25)+"%");
    System.out.println(find_percent(20,40,35)+"%");

}


public static double find_percent(double start,double end,double val){

    end = end- start;
    val = val - start;
    start = 0;

    return((1-(val/end))*100);
}
```

Output:

```
100.0%
0.0%
50.0%
75.0%
25.0%

100.0%
0.0%
75.0%
25.0%
```

Comment: thats working perfectly bro :) thank you so much..I have tried all possible ranges and input values for "x" its working good..

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the corresponding assignment would be

```
double percentage = 1.0f - Math.Abs(x-min)/Math.Abs(max-min);
```

where the absolute function is used to cover the case that `max` and `min` are of different sign.

Comment: but if i give the value x=200 here with range [100,300] the result is 100%. it should be 50% actually..

Comment: If the values `x=200`,`min=100` and `max=300`, are plugged into the expression above, evaluation yields `(x-min)/(max-min)=(200-100)/(300-100)=100/200=50%` which is the desired result.

Comment: hmm i see..its good then i will be able to use that also :)

Comment: yes its working now :) this provides the same result as the answer mentioned by @Jay Solanki . Here it gives the value from 0 to 1 and the former provides the result as percentage from 0 to 100%..